# Add data binding attribute for controls like SeekBar

Tags: android, android-databinding

How can I add data binding attribute for controls that does not provide a method for?

An example is SeekBar that does not have an onProgressChanged attribute for data binding.

I'm also extending the Button class (tri-state button) to add a new property and I'd like to enable it for data binding.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html#attribute_setters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SeekBar does support `android:onProgressChanged`, so you don't need anything special to make it work.

@CommonsWare gave the right answer in the comments:

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html#attribute_setters

There are no magical data binding attributes. They are all brought to you with BindingAdapters and automatic properties. You can look at the source code for existing implementations if you want examples. They are in the com.android.databinding:adapters library. They are all named based on the targeted view class. For example, the attributes targeting `ViewGroup` are in `ViewGroupBindingAdapter`. You can browse the external libraries or type `ViewGroupBindingAdapter` into Android Studio and then click on it to find the source.